# How to override a rails 4 module from the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime, timezone

In my application I need to record the `created_at` based on the current user's time as I need to apply different rules and conditions based on the time user created a record.

This is what I have done:
in the **application.rb**:

```
 config.time_zone = 'Melbourne'
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

However when user from different timezone create a record or update a record it saves as `Melbourne` timezone. I thought default timezone would be set to where user create the record.

Basically I need to be able to do this for the `created_at` and `updated_at`:

`Time.zone.now`

So I did the following in my initialiser folder:

I have added **timestamp.rb** with the following code:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Timestamp
    def self.included(base) #:nodoc:
      base.alias_method_chain :create, :timestamps
      base.alias_method_chain :update, :timestamps

      base.class_inheritable_accessor :record_timestamps, :instance_writer => false
      base.record_timestamps = true
    end

    private
    def create_with_timestamps #:nodoc:
      if record_timestamps
        t = Time.zone.now
        write_attribute('created_at', t) if respond_to?(:created_at) && created_at.nil?
        write_attribute('created_on', t) if respond_to?(:created_on) && created_on.nil?

        write_attribute('updated_at', t) if respond_to?(:updated_at) && updated_at.nil?
        write_attribute('updated_on', t) if respond_to?(:updated_on) && updated_on.nil?
      end
      create_without_timestamps
    end

    def update_with_timestamps(*args) #:nodoc:
        t = Time.zone.now
        write_attribute('updated_at', t) if respond_to?(:updated_at)
        write_attribute('updated_on', t) if respond_to?(:updated_on)
    end
  end
end
```

I restarted the server however nothing has changed, still I get the wrong timezone recordings. If somehow I force Rails to use my Timestamp override this problem would be solved.

This is on my Local machine at about 10:15 AM

Here is an example of `created_at` after `create` is triggered:
 `created_at: "2014-12-09 22:15:09"`

Now when I run the `Time.zone.now` in the console I get 
`Wed, 10 Dec 2014 10:15:09 EST +11:00`

FYI: (Not sure this is matter.)
Database is located on Amazon RDS which is in different timezone too and it is Postgresql.

Comment: `config.time_zone` lets you set an application timezone different from server time. `config.active_record.default_timezone` lets you choose whether AR objects are represented in application time (Melbourne) or database time (UTC). `Time.now` is server time, `Time.zone.now` is application time (Melbourne). Rails does not do client time out of the box because it doesn't know the client's timezone. You must detect the client's timezone and handle conversions manually.

Comment: so when user press submit on the form, in the controller, I get the current_time and then save it for user. If that is the case, what command should I use to get the current time for user? Or should I javascript to get it on the Fly and pass it to rails as a hidden field or something.

Comment: The easiest way is to have a timezone column for each user. Then you would call `Time.now.in_time_zone(user.timezone)`. User's timezone must be a string, not an offset. There are several detection strategies from geolocation to client-side JS to simply asking the user.